# Robust function for manipulation of nested lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a nested list of the form:

```
test = {{"sample1", {"elema", "ppm", 238}, {"elemb", "ppm", 57}, 
                    {"elemc", "w%", 14.23}, {"elemd", "w%", 0.112}}, 
        {"sample2", {"elema", "ppm", 215}, {"elemb", "ppm", 13}, 
                    {"elemc", "w%", 12.13}, {"elemd", "w%", 0.095}}, 
        {"sample3", {"elema", "ppm", 219}, {"elemb", "ppm", 28}, 
                    {"elemc", "w%", 19.11}, {"elemd", "w%", 0.55}}};
```

I want to be able to select and order rows from this list based on another list:

```
samples = {"sample3", "sample1"};
```

and reorder elements based on their label,

```
order =  {"elemd","elemc","elemb","elema"};
```

to end up with something like:

> {{0.55, 19.11, 28, 219}, {0.112, 14.23, 57, 238}}

The main aim is to have a robust re-ordering function of the form

```
trchem[data_, order_, sample_] := ...
```

I have played around with the following:

```
Intersection[sample, #] & /@ test
```

> {{"sample1"}, {}, {"sample3"}}

```
Position[#, test[[All, 1]]] & /@ sample
```

> {{}, {}}

Neither of which are quite right..

I'm sure this is really easy but I can't figure it out at the moment.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**, I like this one more:

```
trchem[data_, order_, sample_] := Outer[
              Sequence @@ Cases[data, {#1, ___, {#2, _, x_}, ___} :> x] &, sample, order]
```

It is shorter but not faster since it scans whole list again and again.

---

Here is **my first approach**:

```
trchem[data_, order_, sample_] := Module[{temp},
       temp = Sequence @@ Cases[data, {#, y___} :> {y}] & /@ sample;

       Map[Function[x, (Sequence @@ Cases[x, {#, y_, z_} :> z] & /@ order)], temp]

      ]

trchem[test, order, samples]
```

> ```
> {{0.55, 19.11, 28, 219}, {0.112, 14.23, 57, 238}}
> ```

I think the code is transparent, if there are quetions feel free to ask. I have choosen `Map` with `Cases` instead of `Sort` based solution. I think it can be faster but we will see.

There is `Function[x, somemapping...` which has to be there because there is double mapping, on `order` while on `temp` so twice "`#&`" will not work since mapping is entangled a little.

---

**Remarks** about OP's atempts:

- Valid usage of `Intersection` would be:

  ```
  Intersection[test, Transpose@{samples}, SameTest -> (Equal @@ (First /@ {##}) &)]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{"sample1", {"elema", "ppm", 238}, <<3>>}, 
  > {"sample3", {"elema", "ppm", 219},  <<3>>}}
  > ```

But it does not preserve `samples` order. Also **`Intersection` is deleting duplicates in its first argument** so in, hypothetical, case where there are `{"sample1", somedata1}` and `{"sample1", somedata2}` you will loose one of them. It is also not efficient to do this if you don't have too.

- Using `Position` may be interesting since it will preserve an order. (but I think `Cases` with `Map` will do the job better):

  ```
  Sequence @@ Position[test[[ ;; , 1]], #] & /@ samples
  Extract[test, %]
  ```

  > ```
  > {{"sample3", {"elema", "ppm", 219},  <<3>>}},
  > {"sample1", {"elema", "ppm", 238}, <<3>>}}
  > ```

Comment: I guess yours might be faster - I tried to stick closer to the OPs plan (maybe I wasn't so successful after all) :). Nice one!

Comment: @PinguinDirk It looks like second halfs of our ideas are quite similar. I used `Map` more because I feel comfortable with using it, also I do not have experience with sorting performance so this is brute force :) I will not be surprised if it is not optimal.

Comment: @geordie I've added couple of things about your approach.

Comment: I really like your edit. Thanks for the detailed explanations!

Comment: @geordie That's great you like it. Thanks for good question that inspired me to play with `Intersection` :)

Answer (score 5):

A bit long for a comment but can definitely be optimized:

```
trchem[data_, order_, sample_] := 
   Last /@ 
     Sort[#, Position[order, #1[[1]]][[1, 1]] < Position[order, #2[[1]]][[1, 1]] &]& /@ 
     Rest /@ Flatten[(Function[x, Select[data, #[[1]] == x &]] /@ sample), 1]
```

so

```
trchem[test,order,samples]
```

(using the params defined in the OP) gives the desired output.

What's going on?

I first select the entries we need using a [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Select.html) (depending on the size of you list etc this could be optimized), by mapping it on the `sample`. After `Flatten`ing, we `Map` `Rest` on it, to get rid of the labels. Finally we [`Sort`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sort.html), using the [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html) in the `order` list. Mapping `Last` on that, we are done.

I tried to follow your logic/idea as much as possible. In regard to the two points you raise/ask at the end of your post, I can only refer you to the Documentation center (have a good look at the order of arguments in [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Position.html)). I hope my approach gives you an idea... (I couldn't get [`Intersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Intersection.html) in my answer :) )

Comment: This is good, thanks! Nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a fairly simple rule-based approach.

First convert the input data to a list of rules:

```
testrules = #1 -> (#1 -> #3 &) @@@ {##2} & @@@ test

(* {"sample1" -> {"elema" -> 238, "elemb" -> 57, "elemc" -> 14.23, "elemd" -> 0.112}, 
 "sample2" -> {"elema" -> 215, "elemb" -> 13, "elemc" -> 12.13, "elemd" -> 0.095}, 
 "sample3" -> {"elema" -> 219, "elemb" -> 28, "elemc" -> 19.11, "elemd" -> 0.55}} *)
```

Then the required output is just:

```
order /. (samples /. testrules)

(* {{0.55, 19.11, 28, 219}, {0.112, 14.23, 57, 238}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I  know its not that pretty looking compared to other answers.but since i spent some time thinking about it i had to post it.

```
     trchem[data_, order_, sample_] := 
     Module[{}, testSample = data[[All, 1]];
     Partition[
      DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[If[sample[[#]] == testSample[[i]],
      DeleteCases[Flatten[Table[If[order[[#]] == data[[i, j, 1]],
           data[[i, j, 3]]], {j, 2, Length[data[[1]]]}] & /@ 
        Range[Length[order]]], Null]
         ], {i, 1, Length[data]}] & /@ Range[Length[sample]]], Null], 
      Length[order]]
      ]
```

Comment: @Kuba Yes u r right.I have edited it

Comment: @Kuba Done.Actually im not able to understand that 3 underscore u have in ur code.it works even with 2.also whats the difference between 2 & 3 underscore

Comment: You are right `__` is enough, the `___` means there could be nothing :) like `{"elema"}`, but it is not this case so, as I said `__` is enough.