# Select list elements based on other list

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to find a nice and clean method to select elements from one list which are in another list or the criteria is based on another list. The ones I want to returned are in `listA` and the ones that contain the matching criteria are in `listB`. `listA` has different dimensions than `listB` and I only apply the criterion on certain subset say, `listA[[All,1]]`. Obviously, not all elements in `listA[[All,1]]` have to be present in `listB` and not all elements of `listB` are present in `listA[[All,1]]` So far, I have come up with the two almost identical methods:

```
listA = {{"a", 1, 3}, {"b", 3, 4}, {"e", 4, 4}, {"r", 2, 2}}
listB = {"a", "c", "d", "e"}
Function[u, Select[listA, #[[1]] == u &]] /@ 
 Intersection[listA[[All, 1]], listB]
Function[u, Select[listA, #[[1]] == u &]] /@ listB
```

Obviously the second one returns also empty sublists which need to be deleted. Both suffer from producing an additional dimension `{{{"a", 1, 3}}, {{"e", 4, 4}}}` which, of cource, can be corrected with flatten. But, I am interested if there is another, a more elegant way, that would keep the structure of `listA`, without having to figure out at which level to flatten (it is simple in the example above)? (to summarize, I already have a working solution, i am just interesting in other or better ways to do it which I am missing, thank you)

Comment: Somewhat related: [4626](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30890/4626). I particularly liked [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30901/4626) rules based approach. A similar method using `ToAssoication` would be worth trying.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
 Select[listA,MemberQ[listB,#[[1]]]&]
```

> {{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}

Answer (score 7):

You can also use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html):

```
Cases[{Alternatives @@ listB, __}] @ listA
```

> {{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}

Answer (score 5):

You can use an association:

```
take = Lookup[AssociationThread[#[[All, 1]] -> #], #2, Nothing] &;
take[listA, listB]
(* {{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Complement[listA, Extract[listA , #] & /@ Position[Intersection[#, listB ] & /@ listA , {}] ]
```

> {{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very tolerant version that works without flattening `listA`. It compares the leaves of the elements of `listA` (extracted with `Level[#, {-1}]`) with the elements of `listB`. This makes it tolerant to reordering of elements in `listA` as well as arbitrary nesting.

```
listA = {{"a", 1, 3}, {"b", 3, 4}, {"e", 4, 4}, {"r", 2, 2}};
listB = {"a", "c", "d", "e"};
Select[listA, IntersectingQ[Level[#, {-1}], listB] &]
```

> {{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}

One more level of nesting:

```
listA = {{{"a", 1, 3}}, {{"b", 3, 4}}, {{"e", 4, 4}}, {{"r", 2, 2}}};
Select[listA, IntersectingQ[Level[#, {-1}], listB] &]
```

> {{{"a", 1, 3}}, {{"e", 4, 4}}}

Crazy nesting:

```
listA = {{{{{{{"a", 1, 3}}}}}}, {{"b", 3, 4}}, {{{2}, {{"e"}, 3}, 4, 4}}, {{{{{{{{"r", 2, 2}}}}}}}}};
Select[listA, IntersectingQ[Level[#, {-1}], listB] &]
```

> {{{{{{{"a", 1, 3}}}}}}, {{{2}, {{"e"}, 3}, 4, 4}}}

Answer (score 3):

An alternative method using `DeleteCases`:

```
DeleteCases[listA, x_ /; FreeQ[listB, x[[1]]]]

(*{{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}*)
```

Or using `Cases`:

```
Cases[listA, x_ /; ! FreeQ[listB, x[[1]]]]

(*{{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
listA = {{"a", 1, 3}, {"b", 3, 4}, {"e", 4, 4}, {"r", 2, 2}};
listB = {"a", "c", "d", "e"};
arule = First@# -> # & /@ listA;

KeyTake[arule, listB] // Values
```

or

```
Pick[listA, KeyMemberQ[arule, #] & /@ listB]
```

---

> {{"a", 1, 3}, {"r", 2, 2}}

Answer (score 2):

`Lookup` also accepts `List`s of `Rule`s:

```
look = MapApply[# -> {##} &] @ listA
```

{"a" -> {"a", 1, 3}, "b" -> {"b", 3, 4}, "e" -> {"e", 4, 4},
"r" -> {"r", 2, 2}}

```
Lookup[look, listB, Nothing]
```

{{"a", 1, 3}, {"e", 4, 4}}

Answer (score 2):

```
Extract[listA,Position[listA[[All,1]],Alternatives@@listB]]

(* {{a,1,3},{e,4,4}} *)
```

In addition:

```
Pick[listA,listA[[All,1]]/.Thread[listB->True]]

(* {{a,1,3},{e,4,4}} *)
```